# Meaning of new block "git_source(:github)" in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

Recently I created a new Rails 5 app, without a git repository. The auto-generated Gemfile contains a new block I had not seen before:

```
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
```

What's the meaning of it? Is it mandatory for every new app?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Its a workaround for a bug in Bundler which can cause sources from github to be loaded via HTTP and not HTTPS - which makes it vulnerable to man in the middle attacks.

`git_source` adds a source which you can use so that the gem is downloaded from a git repository instead of a package from `rubygems.org`.

```
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
```

Would make it so that when you declare:

```
gem 'foo_bar', :github => 'foo/bar'
```

Bundler would attempt to download the gem from `https://github.com/foo/bar.git`.

Since [fixing this would be a breaking change](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/5476) as it would invalidate any existing Gemfile.lock it is fixed in Bundler 2.x. At that point it should be safe to remove this workaround.

Comment: Then, is this an error from some gem recently updated? which gem?

Comment: Another way to work around this issue is to set `bundle config github.https true`

Comment: True @Stefan. But any team is only as secure as its laziest member.

Answer (score 18):

The Bundler :github directive will fetch from `git://github.com/#{repo_name}.git` ([source](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/v1.10.6/lib/bundler/dsl.rb#L214-L217)), which uses the insecure `http` protocol.

This is due to be fixed in future Bundler versions but this snippet is added to the top of the Gemfile to ensure `https` is used in Bundler 1.

Answer (score 8):

If you do not want to add this code to your gemfile but still want to securely access a gem from github you can use the following method:

```
gem 'foo_bar', git: 'https://github.com/foo/bar.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even do:

```rb
git_source(:rails) { |name| "https://github.com/rails/#{name}" }

gem "rails", rails: :rails
```